# Can I use 'Featured Image' as a hero image and a thumbnail?

Tags: functions, theme-development, post-thumbnails

I am finding a lot of great information for using [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) to use this feature as a post hero OR a thumbnail, but I'm struggling to figure out how to use the 'Featured image' as both in my templates.

Here's the gist of what I'm trying do:

1. user uploads a featured image to post, which is cropped to 2400 x 1350 px (hero)
2. image is also scaled and saved as a thumb at 880 x 495 px (pixel perfect scaling ratio from hero)
3. embed hero size `the_post_thumbnail('large')` in `single.php` template and `the_post_thumbnail('thumb')` on the homepage for the post preview

I think I understand how to access and embed the sizes that I would like to use in the appropriate places but I don't understand the workflow for cropping the image on upload and scaling it to multiple sizes. I found [`set_post_thumbnail_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail_size/), which gets me halfway there, but how do I create multiple sizes?

Comment: Sounds like you need to add another image size

Comment: [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

Comment: "I don't understand the workflow for cropping the image on upload and scaling it to multiple sizes" There's no such thing. The image will automatically be cropped into all registered sizes. If you need the user to manually crop either image separately, then they can't both be the featured image.

Comment: @JacobPeattie the aspect ratio is the same in both sizes (16:9) so it only needs to be cropped once and then scaled down to the smaller size. Does it automatically exist in all the other sizes? I'm seeing the default thumbnail and medium sizes on FTP but I can't seem to get my custom sizes to come through.